# Java applet runs locally but not on the host

Tags: java, applet, webserver, localhost

I have written an applet application and integrate it to run under a webpage. It runs properly when I am running the webpage as local HTML file (using file:/// protocol). But when I am running it on a host (tested with http://localhost using XAMPP), it does not work anymore and through exception of ClassNotFound.

My applet classes are packaged under a *.jar file. Is not the jar file loaded in this case? Can anyone give me a suggestion that what can I do to deal with this problem?

---

### Update

I have uploaded the jar file into the same folder as the HTML file. In my case, they are in the DocumentRoot of the Apache server. I can double-click on the HTML file, it works.

But when I query like: localhost/test.html, it does not. My code:

```
<applet 
    code="package/ClassName.class" 
    archive="appletfile.jar">
</applet>
```

I can able load the jar file by: localhost/appletfile.jar

Comment: What is the Class that was not found? Is it in your jar file?

Comment: What is the HTML being used to launch the applet?  Are the HTML and Jar in the same directory?  If not, what is the relevant directory structure?

Comment: It feel like, you have your jar with all program files, but you might have missed the dependency jars..

Comment: -Thilo Yes it is because I can run it locally
-Andrew Yes, it is in the same directory
-Krishnanunni Thanks but I don't think so because I can run it with file protocol

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, it is in the same directory

Comment: @Krishnanunni Thanks but I don't think so because I can run it with file protocol

Comment: BTW - what is the result of a direct fetch on localhost/package/ClassName.class  (or to put that another way, is the applet class also located in the `package` directory of the `DocumentRoot`)?

Comment: localhost/package/ClassName.class
This show a Not found page because it is compressed in a jar file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  That rules out one (of many) possibilites.  Note that I do not get notified of replies to comments I make, unless the reply comment starts with @Andrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html document (in which `<applet/>` tag is used to deploy an applet) and `.jar` file must be   in the same folder.

```
<applet code ="package.AppletClassName" 
        archive = "Sample.jar" 
        width = "200"
        height ="200">
</applet>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Those attributes are nicely aligned BTW.  I cannot bear to look at HTML where the entire opening applet element is on a single line.  Breaking it down an attribute per line is much more clear.

Comment: I have uploaded the jar file into the same folder as the HTML file. In my case, they are in the DocumentRoot of the Apache server. I can double-click on the HTML file, it works. But when I query like: http://localhost/test.html, it does not.
My code: [code]<applet code="package/ClassName.class" archive="appletfile.jar"></applet>[/code]
I can able load the jar file by: http://localhost/appletfile.jar

Comment: As an aside.  [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) is an altogether better way to deploy an applet.  But before introducing that complication, the OP should see it work with at least a single browser for a 'plain old' (and very deprecated) `applet` element.

Comment: An applet element should have `width` & `height` attributes.  The `code` attribute should best be specified as `package.ClassName`.  (Like AVD's example.)  Lacking a `width` and `height`, I am surprised it worked at all (off the local file-system).  What about the other answers re. the class?  Are you certain the CNFE is related to a class that is *actually inside* `appletfile.jar` Jar?

Comment: I have width and height attributes in my <applet> tag. I think the problem is that some how the jar file is not loaded via http. Is there any security problem here?

Comment: ..and just quickly checking for 'other business' while here.  *"I have width and height attributes in my <applet> tag."* A good start, now [validate the HTML](http://validator.w3.org/). *"I think the problem is that some how the jar file is not loaded via http. Is there any security problem here?"*  No.  The fact that you can do a direct fetch on the Jar (off the localhost, as mentioned in your original post) using the browser address bar indicates the server is willing to provide that file to me, you or the JRE.  That is all that is needed for the JRE to be able to load it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but when I change the name of *.jar file to lowercase (all lower case), then it works.

Answer (score 0):

yes!!

Applets able to run in Apache PHP server.The applet is loading from server when you called the html file the applet execute in browser and gives the out put.must and should update your java plugin before run the applet in browser.put your entire applet folder in to apache htdocs folder ,then access that applet in browser....!!It will work.I am sure..

All the Best

Answer (score 0):

Only self signed applets are able to access in browser with security other wise applet not execute with security.You have to signed the applet to execute.